# How add custom ArgumentResolvers without enabling web mvc in spring boot 2?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

[Here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-data-binder) is example about hot to add ArgumentResolver. It uses the following code:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addArgumentResolvers(
      List<HandlerMethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers) {
        argumentResolvers.add(new HeaderVersionArgumentResolver());
    }
}
```

But I use just `@RestController`s without any MVC spring features. But it is needed to reuse some logic for extracting raw request data. Is there a way to add `ArgumentResolver` in spring boot 2 application without implementing `WebMvcConfigurer` interface?

Comment: `@Restcontroller` is part of Spring MVC... So no there isn't... The fact that you return JSON is actually just the another view.

Comment: Really? My IDE can not find any classes with `WebMvcConfigurer` names. So there are no such dependecy in maven. I am using `spring-boot-starter` it does not contain spring mvc depndecy. :(

Comment: You did not add `spring-boot-starter-web` as dependency?

Comment: If you aren't using Web then adding such a argument resolver wouldn't do anything. That is a part of Spring MVC so either way you are using it. You are using Spring Boot , so you are probably using `spring-boot-starter-web` as a dependency (else the `WebMvcConfigurer` wouldn't be available).

Comment: Please post your pom.xml.

Comment: I saw effective pom.xml. You are right dependency `spring-boot-starter-web` is present.

Answer (score 1):

This simply cannot be:

> But I use just @RestControllers without any MVC spring features

I suspect you just want to enhance the Spring Boot MVC, without affecting the existing.

From [String Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html):

> If you want to keep Spring Boot MVC features and you want to add
>   additional MVC configuration (interceptors, formatters, view
>   controllers, and other features), you can add your own @Configuration
>   class of type WebMvcConfigurer but without @EnableWebMvc.

Therefore, if you add that implementation, you won't lose the Spring Boot MVC features. There is no reason not to implement `WebMvcConfigurer` as long as you do not add `@EnableWebMvc`.